# Authentication compatability with game center (Oauth 2.0 and openid 2.0)

Tags: ios, facebook, oauth, openid

I can get authentication through Game Center just fine, but not everyone uses game center...

The basics of my problem is that I would like players to be able to sign into my game through facebook (and possibly google). Basically the same way the "With Friends" games do it. I want to authenticate a player then let him find other players through game center, or invite his friends.

How would I do this would I use Oauth 2.0 or OpenId2.0?

If you could even just point me in the right direction I would be very appreciative.

Extra info: I've enabled game center for my game

Comment: Hey @Ben, have you got a workaround?